Saving QgsSymbol as image with specific DPI using PyQGIS
I want to save QgsMarkerSymbol as a high dpi image (png) invoking the asImage method and then save its result (QImage) in a local directory. I tried using a custom QgsRenderContext object like in the example below, but it didn't change the resulting image quality.
def export_symbol(symbol: QgsSymbol, output_dir: str, dpi: int):
     context = QgsRenderContext()
     context.setDpiTarget(dpi)
     qimage = symbol.asImage(QSize(100,100),context)
     qimage.save(output_dir)

I have also tried updating attributes of QImage object like setDotsPerMeterY/setDotsPerMeterX without any success.
